# How to hide the toolbar when web view is swiped without a navigation controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, web, view, toolbar

I'm using XCode 8 and Swift 3. I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a webView with a toolbar at the bottom, and I'd like to hide the toolbar when the webView is swiped, but `hidesBarsOnSwipe` only works if you have a navigation controller. I'm not using a navigation controller.

If I set `toolBar.isHidden = true`, the toolbar is hidden, but how do I unhide when user swipes up?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This cod**e : Tested in Swift 3

```
  @IBOutlet weak var myToolBar: UIToolbar!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myToolBar.barTintColor = .red // Set any colour or leave that be.
  }

    func hideMyToolBar() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: { 

        self.myToolBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.view.frame.height + self.myToolBar.frame.height, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.myToolBar.frame.height)

    }, completion: nil) 
  }

   func showMyToolBar() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { 

        self.myToolBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.view.frame.height - self.myToolBar.frame.height, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.myToolBar.frame.height)

    }, completion: nil)  
  }
```

**Note:** I am using button action to hide and show toolbar. You have to implement swipe/tap gesture to hide and show toolbar.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much for your time and help!  MUCH appreciated!! :)